# Jquery add substring to url get from indexOf

Tags: jquery, string, url, substring

Hello guys can you give me some tips how can i add the substring after the !google from ondexof? i tried a crazy "var", also made some research, but no example found. Hope you guys can give me some help.
Thank you.

for example from this:

```
    function ai(message){

        var query =  message.indexOf($(this).text());

        if (message.indexOf("!google ") + query ) {
            send_message('https://www.google.com/search?q='+query);
        }
    }
```

i get https://www.google.com/search?q= on a chat bot its working fine, my problem its to add the string **"query"** after **!google**
so if i write to chat bot: **!google books** he will give me https://www.google.com/search?q=books

```
    function send_message(message){

        var prevState = $("#demo-chat-body").html();

        if (prevState.length > 3){
            prevState = prevState + "<br>";
        }

        $("#demo-chat-body").html(prevState +                           
        "<div class='message pull-left'><img src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_JmtCbJ_l52A/S4PwdGRbVzI/AAAAAAAAAVI/tsttLoTeTkA/s400/Avatar-Don-Robot-3.png' class='user-avatar user-avatar-left'></div><a href='#' class='name'>Wowonder Bot</a>"+
"<div class='message incoming pull-left'>"+
"<p class='message-text'>" + message + "</p>"+
"</div>" +
"<div class='clear'></div></div>");


        $(".message-text").hide();
        $(".message-text").delay(500).fadeIn();
        $(".message-text").removeClass("message-text");

    }



    function ai(message){

        var query =  message.indexOf($(this).text());

        if (message.indexOf("!google ") + query ) {
            send_message('https://www.google.com/search?q='+query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Please invest some time to make it clear so people do not have to spend a lot of time understanding what you meant.

Comment: @santon thank your, i edited the question maybe now its better explained. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are saying, I believe this is what you are looking for.
You can call your sendMessage function instead of the innerHTML statement.

```js
function ai(message) {

  var arr = message.split(" ");
  var query = arr[1];

  if (arr[0] === "!google") {

    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML =
      'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + query;
  }
}



ai("!google books");
```

```html
<main>
  <p id="log"></p>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you santon, i did this and works good <3   var arr = message.split(" ");
  var query = arr[1];
  
  if (message.indexOf("!google ") + query ) {
   send_message('https://www.google.com/search?q='+query);
  }

Comment: @filipe: Good to know that worked for you. Please accept my answer in that case.